# SQLite Exception when trying to update a record

Tags: android, android-sqlite

```
//table details 
public static final String TABLE_NAME_Details="details";
public static final String USERNAME="USERNAME";
public static final String PASSWORD="PASSWORD";

//update value
public boolean updatePassword(String LoggedUsername)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    try {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(PASSWORD, "test");

        if (db.isOpen()) {
            db.update(TABLE_NAME_Details, values, USERNAME + "=" + LoggedUsername,null);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("eEmp/DBUpdateUser ", e.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am passing the username to updatePassword() method and trying to change the password of that user with the "test".

But its giving me the exception:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: bvb (code 1):
>   , while compiling: UPDATE details SET PASSWORD=? WHERE USERNAME=bvb

bvb is the username that I entered.

Why is it happening like this?

Comment: In addition to @mustabelMo's answer, you're mixing techniques: half query uses an (unused) parameter, which remains **?** (since you don't pass the parameter), and the rest uses an unescaped string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

invoke the update method using the quotes

```
 updatePassword("'bvb'");
```

or change this line inside the method

```
 db.update(TABLE_NAME_Details, values, USERNAME + "='" + LoggedUsername+"'",null);
```

Comment: I didn't get you @mustabelMo

Comment: when you pass `bvb`you don't escape it, so Sqlite considers it a variable in the sql request, so if you escape it, it will be considered a value